# how can I make a property only accessible from the inherited class?

Tags: c#

I have created a user control and I need that when the property Controls is read it returns a ControlCollection specified by me and not the base property Control.Controls

I did this and it works if I read CustomGroupBox.Controls but if a method that recives a control as parameter (it receives any type of control like CustomGroupBox, Button, Panel, etc) try to read Control.Controls it gets the base ControlCollection.

Let me explain my problem with code

CustomGroupBox.cs

```
public partial class CustomGroupBox : UserControl
{
    Panel Panel1 = null;
    Panel Panel2 = null;
    bool UseBaseControls = true;

    public CustomGroupBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Panel1 = new Panel() { Name = "Panel1" };
        Panel2 = new Panel() { Name = "Panel2" };
        Controls.Add(Panel1);
        Controls.Add(Panel2);

        UseBaseControls = false;
    }

    public new ControlCollection Controls { get { return UseBaseControls ? base.Controls : Panel1.Controls; } }
}
```

Form1.cs

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CustomGroupBox Container = new CustomGroupBox();
        Container.Controls.Add(new Button());
        Container.Controls.Add(new Button());
        Container.Controls.Add(new Button());
        Container.Controls.Add(new Button());

        Control Parameter = Container;

        int i = Container.Controls.Count;               // i=4
        int j = Parameter.Controls.Count;               // j=2
    }
}
```

Does anyone knows what I have to change on CustomGroupBox.cs so j=4 ?

Update:

I can't find a solution, I tried to implement an interfaz like IContainerControl but it does't work.

Comment: Get in the habit of naming your locals starting with small letters. That's the standard in C#. Name properties and fields and methods and types starting with large letters.

Comment: That's just the way `new` works: what's your goal exactly? Maybe there's another way.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the main problem here is that the UserControl.Controls property is not virtual and can therefore not be overridden in your derived `CustomGroupBox` class. In other words, there's no vtable entry for that property's getter.

Thus, any code that perceives the object instance as one of the base class types (`UserControl`, `Control`, etc.) and invokes the `Controls` property will get results from the base class.

Use of the `new` keyword here has enabled you, effectively, to add a brand new property called `Controls` to the `CustomGroupBox` class, but that new property is actually distinct from the property of the same name in the base classes. The only way, then, to invoke your new property's getter is through a variable that's strongly typed as a `CustomGroupBox`.

One technique would be "upcast" your `Parameter` variable in `Form1_Load` to a `CustomGroupBox`, but that may not always be an option for you in more complex scenarios.

You could write code like:

```
Control Parameter = Container;

int j = ((Parameter as CustomGroupBox)?.Controls ?? Parameter.Controls).Count;
```

This code would attempt a safe upcast from type `Control` to `CustomGroupBox` before invoking the `Controls` property getter and fall back to the base class `Controls` property getter if `Parameter` is not actually a `CustomGroupBox`.

Comment: Thx @kkahl, in fact I realized that I can cast `Parameter` as `CustomGroupBox` but like you say it is not always an option. Thinking for example if I compile `CustomGroupBox` in a dll and another developer uses my user control and pass it to a third-party dll Foo(Control Bar) that dll will not get the desired ControlCollection.